# Rails ActiveRecord appears to have ignored a model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, rails-activerecord, assign

I have the following models and associations:

> Status has_many :transactions, foreign_key: :transtatusid
>
> Transaction belongs_to :status, foreign_key: :transstatusid

I had a Transaction record t1 and a Status record s3.  I meant to do the following:

```
 t1.transtatusid = s3.id
 t1.save
```

HOWEVER I instead did this by mistake

```
 t1.transtatusid = s3
 t1.save
```

The thing is that Rails DIDN'T COMPLAIN.  It just ignored the allocation.

Should it have complained? If not, why not?

I user Rails3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.3 with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Rails will ignore errors on save and continue with the old state of the object.
If you want to raise an exception, you have to use save! instead.
Afterwards you can rescue from the thrown error with an error message, flash message or simmilar.